# Best Ebook Reader Applications for Multiple Devices

Tags: google-play-books, software

So I know the **best** is very opinionated, but currently I am managing all my ebooks (All formats) using [Callibre Software for Desktop](https://calibre-ebook.com/) and whenever I have to sync it with other devices I prefer [Google Play Books](https://play.google.com/books) (There I upload the file after converting it to ePub first). So I was seeking for a better option or better management for my library

Comment: I might correct you on some points: first Google Play Books support ePub format the best, it also supports PDF but its not that much Book Friendly on it [(verify here)](https://support.google.com/books/partner/answer/3424254?hl=en)

Comment: Second: to read on Google Play Books one must upload the file (ePub as discussed above) to cloud, for which I said I use calibre as converter - No issue about the conversion

Comment: I need a better solution to do all this